# Excel: How to move text from multiple cells to first cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

i have a hug excel table:

[image]

I need a formula to move data to the first cell, like below.

[image]

please help me to do that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what happens if two cells on the same row have data in them?

Comment: Is it a set number of columns that are populated? That is, will there always only be 6 columns you're looking at? If you want to do this solely with formulas (no VBA), you can insert a new first column, and simply use concatenation: `=A2 & A3 & A4 & A5 & A6 & A7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Just be sure to set the source_rng to the range that you want. Should scale up well too. EDIT: realize now that this doesn't preserve color, will work on that

```
Sub main()
Dim ws                              As Worksheet
Dim source_rng                      As Range
Dim target_rng                      As Range
Dim source_data()                   As Variant
Dim clean_data()                    As Variant
Dim column_count                    As Long
Dim row_count                       As Long
Dim i                               As Long
Dim j                               As Long
Dim k                               As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set source_rng = ws.Range("A1:F19200")

    column_count = source_rng.Columns.Count
    row_count = source_rng.Rows.Count

    ReDim source_data(1 To row_count, 1 To column_count)
    ReDim clean_data(1 To row_count * column_count, 1)
    source_data = source_rng

    k = 1
    For j = 1 To row_count
        For i = 1 To column_count
            If source_data(j, i) <> "" Then
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

    ReDim clean_data(1 To k, 1)

    k = 1
    For j = 1 To row_count
        For i = 1 To column_count
            If source_data(j, i) <> "" Then
                clean_data(k, 0) = source_data(j, i)
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

    source_rng.Clear
    Set target_range = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & UBound(clean_data))
    target_range.value = clean_data
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great... Thank you very much :)